# How can I print a specific part of a JSON object with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I would like to know what to use to transform the document from `JSON` to an array and the print the part of the array the user wants. Also, how can I put it in an `HTML` document so the user can search any part of the array.

Below is the `JSON`.

```js
{
  "A": {
    "1": {
      "1\u00ba": [
        "Semestre 1"
      ]
    },
    "2": {
      "1\u00ba": [
        "Semestre 1"
      ]
    }
  },
  "B": [

  ],
  "c": {
    "2": {
      "1\u00ba": [
        "Semestre 1"
      ]
    },
    "3": {
      "1\u00ba": [
        "Semestre 1"
      ]
    },
    "44": {
      "1\u00ba": [
        "Semestre 1"
      ]
    },
    "G6": {
      "1\u00ba": [
        "Semestre 1"
      ]
    },
    "GP98": {
      "1\u00ba": [
        "Semestre 1"
      ]
    },
    "654": {
      "1\u00ba": [
        "Semestre 1"
      ]
    },
    "5556": {
      "1\u00ba": [
        "Semestre 1"
      ]
    },
    "7654": {
      "1\u00ba": [
        "Semestre 1"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: show your json and expected output?

Comment: {
 "A": {
  "1": {
   "1\u00ba": ["Semestre 1"]
  },
  "2": {
   "1\u00ba": ["Semestre 1"]
  }
 },
 "B": [],
 "c": {
  "2": {
   "1\u00ba": ["Semestre 1"]
  },
  "3": {
   "1\u00ba": ["Semestre 1"]
  },
  "44": {
   "1\u00ba": ["Semestre 1"]
  },
  "G6": {
   "1\u00ba": ["Semestre 1"]
  },
  "GP98": {
   "1\u00ba": ["Semestre 1"]
  },
  "654": {
   "1\u00ba": ["Semestre 1"]
  },
  "5556": {
   "1\u00ba": ["Semestre 1"]
  },
  "7654": {
   "1\u00ba": ["Semestre 1"]
  }
 }
}

Comment: The output tha I want is to select for example A and get all ist data apart in diferent strings.

Comment: Are you trying to select one part of the JSON (`"A"`) and print all of the keys and  values as an array of strings?

Comment: Yes, that is what im trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want your strings/collection of strings to look like you can do one of the below options.

**[JSON.Stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#targetText=The%20JSON.stringify()%20method,a%20replacer%20array%20is%20specified.)** will convert a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string.

```
printDataWithStringify = (x) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data[x]))
}

> {"1":{"1º":["Semestre 1"]},"2":{"1º":["Semestre 1"]}}
```

If you want to go even further, you can try the below code.

```
var printedStrings = []

checkNestedData = (x, y) => {

  if (typeof(x[y]) === 'object' && !Array.isArray(x[y][property1])) {
    printedStrings.push(y)
    for (var property1 in x[y]) {
      checkNestedData(x[y], property1)
    }
  } else {
    printedStrings.push(x[y]);
  }

}


printDataWithKeysAndValues = (x) => {
  var part = data[x]
  for (var property1 in part) {
    checkNestedData(part, property1)
  }
  console.log(printedStrings)
}

> 1,1º,Semestre 1,2,1º,Semestre 1
```

The above code utilizes a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop which is used to loop through JavaScript objects. `part` is the object you get when you retrieve information from `data` at the key of `x` (in this case, `"A"`). `property1` represents the key for the current object (`part`) and is the iterator for the `for...in` loop as we loop through `part`.

To take it even further, `checkNestedData` checks to see if there is another object nested in the current object. If it's an object (that doesn't have a array for a child), you push `y` (remember this is the key (`property1`) from the original loop) into the intialized `printedStrings` array. Then perform another loop and you run `checkNestedData` recursively on the current iterative in the new loop.

This recursive callback will run until the last child is not a populated object.

Once we've looped through the entire object, storing the keys and values we've extracted from the object (including nested objects) we simply `console.log` the final array which contains all of our keys and value from that portion (`"A"`) of data.

Depending on how you want the string to be formatted, you can append/remove things from the strings via interpolation or concatenation. But this solution should get you every key and value and store them as a string in an array.

```js
var data = {
  "A": {
    "1": {
      "1\u00ba": [
        "Semestre 1"
      ]
    },
    "2": {
      "1\u00ba": [
        "Semestre 1"
      ]
    }
  },
  "B": [

  ],
  "c": {
    "2": {
      "1\u00ba": [
        "Semestre 1"
      ]
    },
    "3": {
      "1\u00ba": [
        "Semestre 1"
      ]
    },
    "44": {
      "1\u00ba": [
        "Semestre 1"
      ]
    },
    "G6": {
      "1\u00ba": [
        "Semestre 1"
      ]
    },
    "GP98": {
      "1\u00ba": [
        "Semestre 1"
      ]
    },
    "654": {
      "1\u00ba": [
        "Semestre 1"
      ]
    },
    "5556": {
      "1\u00ba": [
        "Semestre 1"
      ]
    },
    "7654": {
      "1\u00ba": [
        "Semestre 1"
      ]
    }
  }
}

printDataWithStringify = (x) => {
  console.log('STRINGIFY: ' + JSON.stringify(data[x]))
}

var printedStrings = []

checkNestedData = (x, y) => {

  if (typeof(x[y]) === 'object' && !Array.isArray(x[y][property1])) {
    printedStrings.push(y)
    for (var property1 in x[y]) {
      checkNestedData(x[y], property1)
    }
  } else {
    printedStrings.push(x[y]);
  }

}


printDataWithKeysAndValues = (x) => {
  var part = data[x]
  for (var property1 in part) {
    checkNestedData(part, property1)
  }
  console.log('ALL KEYS AND VALUES: ' + printedStrings)
}


printDataWithStringify("A")
printDataWithKeysAndValues("A")
```

Comment: can you help me with one more thing plz?

Comment: I will put it as if I was answering my problem

Comment: I can help you but why are you unaccepting the answer? And put what as if you were answering your problem?

Comment: Im sorry I took it off to see if I could put more comments but it did not let me and I got distracted